# What token do I need for PowerBI's REST API to refresh a dataset?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory

I've been reading over Microsoft's documentation for PowerBI's REST API, but I am getting confused. I am attempting to refresh a PowerBI report I have, through R.
The information that I am currently able to receive are:

- Dataset ID
- Tenant ID
- Object ID

I am also able to retrieve an access token using Powershell and PowerBI's cmdlets:

```
Login-PowerBI
Get-PowerBIAccessToken -AsString
```

Some sources on the internet say I have to register my report through Azure Portal, in order to get another type of access token, which I currently cannot do as I do not have admin privileges. Is there a way around this?

Also, if I use PowerBI's web service that allows you to try out the API:

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset#code-try-0)

I am able to get that other access token, simply by signing in and choosing the proper Azure tenant. From here I am able to refresh the report, but of course I want to automate this through R, rather than using the web sample. So, how is that I retrieve this token that allows me to refresh my report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To refresh the dataset you need the access token must have **`Dataset.ReadWrite.All`** API permission.

I generated the **access token** via PowerShell:

```
Login-PowerBI
Get-PowerBIAccessToken -AsString
```

[image]

When you decode the access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), you will be able to see that  **`Dataset.ReadWrite.All`**  is present and the **aud** is `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api`

[image]

By using the above token, **I am able to successfully refresh the dataset**:

*For sample, I passed the token in Postman and called the API*

```json
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/DataSetID/refreshes

{

"type": "full",
"commitMode": "transactional",
"objects": [
{
"table": "Customer",
"partition": "Ruk"
}
],
"applyRefreshPolicy": "false"
}
```

[image]

When checked in Power BI portal **the dataset is refreshed** successfully:

[image]

Hence you can pass the token you are generating via PowerShell and no need of creating Microsoft Entra application.

Comment: Thank you, I realized now what I was doing wrong, but I have a follow up question. This method requires me to log-in manually every time. I have tried to save my credentials to further automate the process, however receive an error that I must sign in manually due to MFA being enabled. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: If MFA is enabled then there is no way to automate the login